# Cloned node.js project gives a weird error into log

Tags: node.js

Git module
https://github.com/eugenioclrc/agar.io-clone

```
> gulp run

[14:50:54] Using gulpfile C:\....\gulpfile.js
[14:50:54] Starting 'lint'...
[14:50:54] Starting 'move-client'...
[14:50:57] Finished 'move-client' after 2.84 s
[14:50:57] Finished 'lint' after 2.88 s
[14:50:57] Starting 'build-client'...
[14:50:57] Starting 'build-server'...
[14:50:57] Starting 'test'...
[14:50:57] Finished 'test' after 2.21 ms


  util.js
    #massToRadius
      V should return non-zero radius on zero input
      V should convert masses to a circle radius
[14:50:58] Finished 'build-server' after 848 ms
    #validNick
      V should allow empty player nicknames
      V should allow ascii character nicknames
      V should disallow unicode-dependent alphabets
      V should disallow spaces in nicknames
    #log
      1) should compute the log_{base} of a number
    #getDistance
      V should return a positive number


  7 passing (390ms)
  1 failing

  1) util.js #log should compute the log_{base} of a number:

      AssertionError: expected 2.0000000000000004 to deeply equal 2
      + expected - actual

      -2.0000000000000004
      +2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test is failing at `#log @should compute the log_{base} of a number`

The test itself, problem in `var logNineThree = util.log(9,3);`

```
  describe('#log', function () {

    it('should compute the log_{base} of a number', function () {
      var base10 = util.log(1, 10),
          base2  = util.log(1, 2);

      var identity = util.log(10, 10);

      var logNineThree = util.log(9,3);

      //  log(1) should equal 0, no matter the base
      expect(base10).to.eql(base2);

      // log(n,n) === 1
      expect(identity).to.eql(1);

      // perform a trivial log calculation: 3^2 === 9
      expect(logNineThree).to.eql(2);
    });

  });
```

The `util.log`

```
// overwrite Math.log function
exports.log = (function () {
    var log = Math.log;
    return function (n, base) {
        return log(n) / (base ? log(base) : 1);
    };
})();
```

Conclusion

**Safari Browser:** `Math.log(3) === 1.0986122886681098`
**Chrome Browser:** `Math.log(3) === 1.0986122886681096`
**MacOS Nodejs v8.2.1:** `Math.log(3) === 1.0986122886681096`
**Unix Terminal Online:** `echo 'l(3)' | bc -l === 1.0986122886681096 9139`<sup>[try](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_terminal_online.php)</sup>

Probably you have different OperatingSystem/Environment than original repository developer

Comment: tnx, but would it help to use node 4 as another answerer recommends

Comment: What if other function will work differently, you will switch again? Ain't good, thats why docker was made

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your node version I think.

create a file like this

```
// log-check.js
// from https://github.com/eugenioclrc/agar.io-clone/blob/master/src/server/lib/util.js 
function multibaselog(n, base) {
  return Math.log(n) / (base ? Math.log(base) : 1);
}

const log93 = multibaselog(9,3)
console.log(log93)
console.log(log93 === 2);
```

then try it with node 4

```
$ nvm use 4
$ node log-check.js 
2
true
```

(works)

and then try it with node 8

```
$ nvm use 8
$ node log-check.js 
2.0000000000000004
false
```

(nope)

If you switch to an earlier version of node, I think this test will pass.

Comment: thanks, my windows does not have nvm command, is it extra tool?

Comment: oh no sorry.  no idea how to switch node versions on windows